# Combinatorics problem regarding two kinds of elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to understand this problem as exposed in William Feller's *An introduction to probability theory and its applications*:

> *(d) Flags of one or two colors.* In example (1.f) it was shown that *r* flags can be displayed on *n* poles in *N = n(n+ 1) ... (n+r-1)* different ways. We now consider the same problem for flags of one
>   color (considered indistinguishable). Numbering the flags of such a
>   display yields exactly *r!* displays of *r* distinguishable flags and
>   hence *r* flags of the same color can be displayed in *N/r!* ways.

I understand that a group of *r* distinguishable elements yield *r!* ordered samples of size *r*. But I do not understand why is it that *r*
undistinguished flags can be displayed in *N/r!* ways. As I think about it, since they are supposed to be undistinguished, shouldn't there be only one way to order them? Does *N/r!* always yield 1? If so, why?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put stickers with numbers $1$ to $r$ on the flags. Now after displaying the $r$ flags on $n$ poles, you can rearrange the stickers in $r!$ ways. That is, $r!$ different ways to display *distinguishable* flags correspond to $1$ way to display *indistinguishable* flags. Hence, if there are $N$ ways to display distinguishable flags, then there are $N/r!$ ways to display indistinguishable flags. The number $N/r!$ is *not* always $1$. For example if there are $n=2$ poles and $r=3$ indistinguishable flags there are $4$ ways to display them (indexed by the number of flags on the first pole). In fact displaying $r$ indistinguishable flags on $n$ poles counts the number of ordered number partitions of $r$ into $n$ non-negative parts, in the example with $n=2$, $r=3$ the displays correspond to the $4$ partitions
$$
0+3, 1+2, 2+1, 3+0.
$$